# How to find out the mean of beta distribution

Tags: probability

How to evaluate the mean of a beta (a,b) random variable from its probi density function,you may consider $X=x \in (0,1)$.I tried to use integration but i am not sure how to reduce to most simplest form as a may not be a integer.

Comment: Note that the mean of a $\beta$-distribution does not have to be an integer.

Comment: Write the integral formula for $E[X]$ and observe that except for the constant having the wrong value, that integral is the area under the pdf of a _different_ beta random variable $Y$ (i.e. with different parameters than $(a,b)$). So, write the integrand as $Af_Y(x)$ where $f_Y(x)$ is this new pdf and get that $$E[X] = A\int_0^1 f_Y(x) \mathrm dx = A.$$